# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sinh^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, catalans-constant

I have given my friend an integral that I genuinely don't know how to calculate:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sinh^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$$
He tried differentiating under the integral and complex integration, neither of which worked.

I would love to see a way of calculating this. I know for a fact that it equals Catalan's Constant ~$.915$.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: If anyone is curious where I found this, I found it under the article for Catalan's Constant in [Wolfram Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Comment: Is this a fun question?

Comment: Quick: what is $\arcsin(\sin(x))$? No calculus, please.

Comment: @Nilknarf Silly typo! Question fixed!

Comment: @TomHimler You gave your friend a problem that **you** can't solve!? That's a dirty trick! >:D

Comment: @TomHimler Tell your friend that he should give up anyway - [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arcsinh(sin+x)+dx) reveals the indefinite integral is way too complicated for a human to solve.

Comment: @TobyMak But... that's an **indefinite** integral! There are all kinds of tricks for definite integrals that can't be applied to indefinite ones.

Comment: I didn't realise that - however it looks like that somehow the $\cos(x) + i \sqrt{\sin^2 x + 1}$ could be simplified when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: How do you know that it equals Catalan's constant?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I linked the article with the integral.

Comment: There's an explanation of sorts given at the source that is cited in *that* article. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/catalan/catalan.htm

Comment: An interesting question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $a\in(0,1)$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)\,dx}{\sqrt{1+a^2 \sin^2 x}}=\frac{\arctan a}{a} $$
hence by applying $\int_{0}^{1}(\ldots)\,da $ to both sides we get
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\operatorname{arcsinh}(\sin x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}}{(2n+1)}\,da = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=G. $$
Differentiation under the integral sign **does** work.

---

An alternative way is to notice that the Taylor series of the (hyperbolic) arcsine function and the integrals $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{2n+1}\,dx$ interact by simplifying each other:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\operatorname{arcsinh}(\sin x)\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^n}{(2n+1)4^n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{2n+1}\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}. $$
This is reminiscent of one of Euler's proofs of the Basel problem.